# Existence of smooth diffeomorphism $f$ of open ball onto itself with $f(0) = p$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to show that for every point $p$ of the open $n$-disk $B^n$, there exists a smooth diffeomorphism $B^n \to B^n$ sending $0$ to $p$. Certainly, it seems intuitively obvious for points $p$ that are very close to $0$, but I am not used to explicit constructions of continuous/differentiable maps.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a diffeomorphism from $B^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, translate the image of $p$ to the image of $0$ and then apply the inverse diffeomorphism.

Comment: @Pedro: This is just saying to solve the problem to solve the problem. Also, remember the diffeomorphism needs to map $B^n$ to $B^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin i didn't understand, doesn't this idea work?

Comment: I think @Pedro's idea works fine; I don't understand Ted's objection either. If $\phi\colon B^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is any diffeomorphism (such as $\phi(x) = x/\sqrt{1-|x|^2}$), and $\tau\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ is the translation $\tau(x) = x + \phi(p)$, then $\phi^{-1}\circ \tau \circ \phi$ is an explicit diffeomorphism from $B^n$ to $B^n$ that sends $0$ to $p$.

Comment: Check "Homogeneity Lemma" from Milnor's book "Topology from the differential view point". He constructed a map that has even more properties.

Comment: Ah, @JackLee. I misread Pedro's suggestion. I didn't see the conjugation. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: Look for a diffeomorphism that is the identity outside a neighborhood of a path joining $0$ and $p$. You might think of getting this diffeomorphism by finding the flow of a vector field (which should therefore be $0$ outside said neighborhood).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to find, although I couldn't even figure out how to patch things up continuously. I guess it's time I read up on vector fields then.

Comment: Hi Ted -- this works, of course. But if the OP doesn't need the diffeomorphism to be the identity near the boundary, then @Pedro's argument is probably easier. See my comment above.

Comment: Yup. @Pedro and I posted simultaneously. I was suggesting my approach because it is applicable in far more general situations :P (Oh, and, hi, Jack :) )